# Socket leak in multiprocessing manager

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, ipc

I am writing a Python application where there is Master processes which creates a multiprocessing.manager object and a Queue(named as ListenQueue) in it.
Later this main process starts child processes(around 8), to whom it sends the above ListenQueue object along with a newly created Manager.Queue object(named as ProcQueue).
This ProcQueue object is queue created per child process, on which they keep listen for messages. Similarly Main process is also listening on ListenQueue for messages from child processes.

So here is the big picture,

Main process:

```
while True:
    msg = ListenQueue.get()
    process msg ...
```

Child process:

```
while True:
    msg1 = ProcQueue.get()
    process msg1
```

Now when I do want to send messages to child processed, I add it to individual ProcQueue with,

```
Child1.ProcQueue.put(msg2)
Child2.ProcQueue.put(msg2)
....
```

And when I child want send message to Main process they do,

```
ListenQueue.put(msg3)
```

Now the problem is when child process sends a message to main process, it opens a socket right when put() is called. (checked this with "`lsof -p <pid> | grep socket`")
But when Main process is sending any message it does not open any new socket for each put message.

I tried using multiprocessing.Queue, but it looks like uses some synchronization/locking and makes it slow when hundreds of messages are being exchanged.

So this socket count keeps increasing to some max number(around 1024), and the Queue becomes inaccessible with `EOFError` exception to sender process.

How do I make sure either the new sockets are not opened or they are closed immediately.

Comment: What version of Python is this with?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on a Linux machine using Python 2.7 or Python 3.4. Can you provide a small, complete sample program that reproduces the issue for you?

Comment: Its on Ubuntu 12.04.4 with Python 2.7.3. I will post the sample program soon.

Comment: I think you are opening a socket for every message thats why you are hitting the max 1024 which is FD_SETSIZE. You need to remember the socket fd and re use them.

Comment: I dont have your full code but you need to have a listen socket for main and n listen socket for your n child, they all need to run in a seperate threads, if you want to do both send and receive and some way to synchronize send and receive.